# Data Query based on the drop down selection based on the dependent/independent drop down validation list

Tags: excel, list, validation, dropdown

***Screenshot 1:***
[image]

***Screenshot 2:***
[image]

Hi Guys,

Need help with the Data Query based on the drop down selection based on the dependent/independent drop down validation list

Sample Images attached

I tried various formulas but was not able to get it working.

I cannot use INDIRECT because these drop down list are independent (or may be dependent)

I have a Metrics Table in my Consolidated Sheet and i have 10 teams (Team 1, Team 2...Team 9), 3 Environments (Production, Non Prod, No Field, All).

I have 10 other Sheets (Team 1, Team 2... Team 9). Each Sheet has same Metrics Table for All, Production, Non Prod, No Field. From Team 1 Sheet to Team 9 Sheet same format.

In the Consolidated, it is the same Metrics Table and format, however i have put 2 drop down Validation Lists. Independent Drop Downs (INDIRECT is not required) or what if that is made as related field and display only when the other Drop down is selected. This looks like a good one. So i will go with the dependent dropdowns

Requirement is, when i select the Team from the Team Drop Down List, and based on the selection from the dependent drop down list that is (Environment) it should pull the data from the respective teams sheet.

Not sure what is the best approach to get this working. Tried vlooks but was not able to achieve.

Hope there is a alternative to get this working.

Regards
Ajay

Comment: Is there any solution for this please

Comment: guys, were you able to help me out on this please